# Which COUNTIF statement should I use for counting from another sheet in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to use a vba COUNTIF statement for a table using data from another sheet in the same file. Id only like to count the amount of records that have the info received column value as "Outstanding" AND the Job Description column value as "Substation Location". Any ideas on what line I should use?

I have tried using various COUNTIF statement but cant seem to get a count of the rows I require.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How did you use the Countif? Give us the syntax you tried. Shouldn't this be an excel formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example**

Replace the sheet name `Sheet5` with the name of the data sheet.

Instead of `180` type the last row number of the data sheet.

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet5!K2:K180,"=" &Sheet5!$K$8,Sheet5!N2:N180,"="&Sheet5!$N$3)
```

or use literal in criteria

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet5!K2:K180,"=Ground Mounted Substation Location",Sheet5!N2:N180,"=Outstanding")
```

This is the result of a test table

The `;` mark is because of the local numbering format of my system. Use comma as in the example.

[image]